# GCDAsyncUdpSocket The data received is different from android. Is there anything that needs to be changed? Like a subnet mask or something?

Tags: objective-c

I am using udp to search the device. But it doesn't receive the same data as android

```
self.socket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)];
[self.socket localPort];
NSError *error;
[self.socket bindToPort:9200 error:&error];
[self.socket enableBroadcast:YES error:&error];
//data 
[self.socket sendData:data toHost:@"255.255.255.255" port:9200 withTimeout:-1 tag:0];

-(void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromAddress:(NSData *)address withFilterContext:(id)filterContext{
    NSString *base64Response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

```
{
  "from_account": "xxxxxxx",
  "server_ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "server_port": 80,
  "server_mac": "8c85903b1037",
  "device_type": "xxxxxxxx",
  "dev_uptype": 17,
  "post_all": "/lua",
  "get_all": "/lua/getall",
  "app_id": "1000000002",
  "msg_type": "search",
  "from_role": "shared_company",
  "command": "query"
}
```

This is the data that android received

```
{"command":"query","from_role":"hcomm","from_account":"ac35eecf8723","app_id":"1000000003","hcomm_mac":"ac35eecf8723","msg_type":"search"}
```

This is the data that iOS received.

What else needs to be modified to make the data received the same ?

Comment: I think you should ask your's backend team why response is different.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the framework I'm using? Because now there is a gateway broadcast and central broadcast. But I can only receive the central control broadcast. No gateway broadcast was received. The back end doesn't know where to find the reason. Now I can only find them if I have no problem